# How to remove line matching specific pattern from a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, line

1. I know sed could be used to delete specific line from file:

   ```
   sed -i "/pattern/d" file
   ```
2. While the pattern of my case includes slash, like `/var/log`,

   So I know I need escape: `sed -i "/\/tmp\/dir/d" file`
3. However, for my case, the pattern is dynamic, should be a variable
   in a shell file, so I have to convert the variable value to replace
   `"/" with "\\/"`, then got this:

   ```
    sed -i "/^${pattern_variable//\\//\\\\\\/}$/d" file
   ```

My question is, is there any better implementation which is more readable or simpler? Not only `sed`, other utility is also acceptable. Is it possible to handle not only `slash` but also other various symbols, like backslash or # ()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use char other than `/`:

```
sed "\#$varHasSlash#d"
```

example:

```
kent$  foo="b/c"

kent$  echo "a
ab/cd
e"|sed "\#$foo#d"
a
e
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, it works. I tried to use another delimiter other than the slash, however missed the beginning backslash, that's why it didn't work for me.

Comment: The solution is OK for my current issue. What if there's backslash in the pattern?

Comment: @user3093552 then escape it.